# Kaa Endpoint SDK's for Mbed OS?

Tags: kaa, mbed

Is there a roadmap for Kaa to release Endpoint SDK's for Mbed OS?
Or do anyone have previously done just that, connect to Kaa using Mbed OS?

Will appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The Kaa C SDK is portable, and the [platform implementations](https://github.com/kaaproject/kaa/tree/master/client/client-multi/client-c/src/kaa/platform-impl) look pretty simple as long as you have socket primitives (which there are in Mbed OS 5).

So porting the SDK to Mbed should be pretty straight-forward.